# How to change language and also RTL and LRT in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a select box that will have the option to change language and also change RTL and LTR

- In Hebrew - the language will change to Hebrew and will be RTL
- In English - the language will change to English and will be LTR

I tried to do a side change by the following code in `main.dart`:

```
  return Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: LandingScreen(),
  );
```

But I want the side and also the language to change by choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store current selected language in a variable and update the textDirection Accordingly.

To store a selected language, You can use enums.

```
enum Language = {
   English,
   Hebrew
}
...

Language selectedLang = Language.English;
...

void changeLang(Language lang){
 setState((){
    selectedLang = lang;
 });
}
...
return Directionality(
    textDirection: selectedLang == Language.Hebrew ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltl,
    child: LandingScreen(),
  );
```

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: How this change to hebrew?
I need install..something?
thank you

Comment: And I want this all pages
What is the right way to do it?

Comment: " ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              print(this.selectedLang);
              Directionality(textDirection: selectedLang==Language.Hebrew?TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr, child:MyApp());
            }, child: (Text('jjj')))"
don't work

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization